# Drupal: can I assign different order to header (for Views) / body fields in my nodes?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I selecting which fields to show in the Headers and in the Body of my nodes, in the "Manage Fields" settings of my content type.

However I would like to have different order for header elements and node elements.

Is this feasable ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a number of ways you can achieve this. One of them is through the panels module - http://drupal.org/project/panels - another is through the node template file. If you are able to edit your Drupal theme, you could create a new template file for the type of node you wish to customise - called node-[type].tpl.php in your theme directory. You can base this template file on node.tpl.php, and instead of echoing out the body of the node, you choose which fields from the node object you wish to use. See http://drupal.org/theme-guide for more.

Comment: uhm ok thanks.. so, in this way, if I change the order of fields in my node the header fields is not going to be the same, right ?

Comment: What exactly is the "header fields"? Do you mean the node title?

Comment: I meant the Teaser fields. Not header, sorry. There are 2 columns in Content Types - Manage Fields

Comment: You can define specific templates for node-teaser, so yes, you can get the same control over them.